# How many cores are available in this case?

Tags: linux, centos, central-processing-unit, rhel4, multi-core

We're managing 2 production server.  One is RHEL4 and other one is CentOS5.

In order to find the load average, I need to determine how many cores the server has got. I used the command `$ grep cores /proc/cpuinfo` to find the no. of cores available.

Output from RHEL4:

```
cpu cores       : 2
cpu cores       : 2
cpu cores       : 2
cpu cores       : 2
```

Output from CentOS5:

```
cpu cores       : 1
cpu cores       : 1
cpu cores       : 1
cpu cores       : 1
```

My question is, from the output of RHEL4 above, I could see `cpu cores : 2` with 4 entries.  So, is it 8 cores or 4 cores?  What does 2 mean here?

In case of CentOS5, it is evident that it is 4 cores.

I also referred this link: [Howto: Linux detect or find out a dual-core cpu](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-identify-whether-cpu-dual-core-or-not/)

Answer (score 1):

if see in `#cat /proc/cpuinfo` the count start from 0,1,2,3,4. In you RHEL 4 box you have 4 core and your Cent OS 2 core from the value.

Comment: I believe, by *count*, you mean the `processor` here, which appears as the first element.  In both servers, I can see entries for 0,1,2,3.  How do you say CentOS has got 2 core?  Can you explain little bit about how would you find?  Am little confused, when you say CentOS has got only 2 cores here.  I thought it is 4 cores.

Comment: hi Gnanam, it show 2 time entry  of you core so on that base :)

Answer (score 0):

`[root@example ~]# grep cores /proc/cpuinfo`
`cpu cores  : 2`
`cpu cores  : 2`
`[root@example ~]#`

`[root@example ~]# cat /proc/cpuinfo` 
`processor  : 0`
`vendor_id  : GenuineIntel`
`cpu family : 6`
`model      : 23`
`model name : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E8335  @ 2.66GHz`
`stepping   : 6`
`cpu MHz        : 415.293`
`cache size : 6144 KB`
`physical id    : 0`
`siblings   : 2`
`core id        : 0`
`cpu cores  : 2`
`apicid     : 0`
`initial apicid : 0`
`fdiv_bug   : no`
`hlt_bug        : no`
`f00f_bug   : no`
`coma_bug   : no`
`fpu        : yes`
`fpu_exception  : yes`
`cpuid level    : 5`
`wp     : yes`
`flags      : fpu vme de pse tsc msr mce cx8 apic mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush` `mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht constant_tsc pni ssse3`
`bogomips   : 830.58`
`clflush size   : 64`
`cache_alignment    : 64`
`address sizes  : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual`
`power management:`

`processor  : 1`
`vendor_id  : GenuineIntel`
`cpu family : 6`
`model      : 23`
`model name : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E8335  @ 2.66GHz`
`stepping   : 6`
`cpu MHz        : 415.293`
`cache size : 6144 KB`
`physical id    : 0`
`siblings   : 2`
`core id        : 1`
`cpu cores  : 2`
`apicid     : 1`
`initial apicid : 1`
`fdiv_bug   : no`
`hlt_bug        : no`
`f00f_bug   : no`
`coma_bug   : no`
`fpu        : yes`
`fpu_exception  : yes`
`cpuid level    : 5`
`wp     : yes`
`flags      : fpu vme de pse tsc msr mce cx8 apic mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush` `mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht constant_tsc pni ssse3`
`bogomips   : 1070.73`
`clflush size   : 64`
`cache_alignment    : 64`
`address sizes  : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual`
`power management:`

Comment: Please edit your previous answer to include the output rather than create a new one.